# Summaries based on one reference column compared to the other columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, summarize

I want to get sums of a variable depending on the other variable's `na` or `non-na` values in `R`. A working example code is below:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,NA,4),
                 B = c(NA,2,3,NA,5),
                 C = c(3,4,NA,NA,NA),
                 REF = c(10,20,30,40,50))

df.na <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(-REF),is.na)

sums <- matrix(0,2,3)
row.names(sums) <- c("NON-NA","NA")
colnames(sums) <- c("A","B","C")

for(i in 1:3){
  sums[,i] <- df.na %>% group_by_at(i) %>% summarise(sum=sum(REF)) %>% select(sum) %>% unlist()
}

> sums
         A   B   C
NON-NA 110 100  30
NA      40  50 120
```

For example, since  4th term in the `A` column is `NA`, the corresponding column values are `30` and `10+20+3+50 = 150-30 = 120` in `sums` object.

My question is how do I get this output without a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `pivot_` functions from `tidyr`. The approach pivots to a longer form so that you can group by column name and whether the column value is NA.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("A", "B", "C")) %>%
  mutate(isna = is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(name, isna) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(REF)) %>%
  pivot_wider()

  isna      A     B     C
  <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE   110   100    30
2 TRUE     40    50   120
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,NA,4),
                 B = c(NA,2,3,NA,5),
                 C = c(3,4,NA,NA,NA),
                 REF = c(10,20,30,40,50))

library(tidyverse)
imap(.x = df[1:3],
    .f = ~ df %>%
      group_by(grp = is.na(.x)) %>%
      summarise(!!.y := sum(REF, na.rm = T))) %>% 
  reduce(left_join)
#> Joining, by = "grp"
#> Joining, by = "grp"
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   grp       A     B     C
#>   <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 FALSE   110   100    30
#> 2 TRUE     40    50   120
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>